# Google Analytics — Question on how it affects search results on Google

Tags: google-analytics

Simple true or false: Having Google Analytics installed on your page will automatically cause that page to be indexed by Google and appear in their search results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have to say false.  I have a site with tens of thousands of pages, all of which have Google Analytics on them, but only a relatively small portion of them are indexed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe Google has an official policy on this. If Google didn't already know about your site and you added it to analytics, it might crawl it, but that's not guaranteed.

You can always control whether Google is indexing your page or not though using `robots.txt`, and even if you use Google Analytics, googlebot will still obey `robots.txt`. You may want to use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) — webmaster tools lets you see indexing stats for your site, such as the last time each page was accessed, crawl errors, etc. It's very useful for keeping tabs on how google is interacting with your site.